# Sumerian cuneiform dictionary?

Tags: language, research, sumer

Is there a single, unified place where one can look up cuneiform signs for Sumerian words?  Unicode now supports cuneiform, but every source I've found has only transliterations, not actual cuneiform.

For example, I'd like to find this:

> 

instead of this:

> ki-en-ĝir

Once again, I find myself wishing there were a [sumerian.stackexchange.com](http://sumerian.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There is, however, a http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ ... :-)

Comment: @T.E.D., do you think this would be a better fit there?

Comment: [][][]? Apparently Google Chrome does not. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a source request.